# JTable Cell Color for a give cell indexes

Tags: java, swing

Can someone give me an example of how to set background color of a particular cell in a JTable for a given row and column index? I am unable to find an example of how to do this. Plenty of examples on getting the value in a cell, but not the background color of a cell.

Comment: Are you trying to set the color, or get it, or both?

Comment: get the value at the cell and set the cell color according to the cell value

Comment: check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html